# R: creating a Date object from a for loop

Tags: r, loops, date

Why do these two lines of code yield objects with different classes (and how to get around this, ie., to get a Date object from the for loop)?

`seq(as.Date("10032020", format = "%d%m%Y"),Sys.Date(),1)`

`for (days in seq(as.Date("10032020", format = "%d%m%Y"),Sys.Date(),1)){print((days))}`

Thanks!
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `seq_along` to avoid the coersion of `Date` class to its integer storage mode

```
v1 <- seq(as.Date("10032020", format = "%d%m%Y"),Sys.Date(),1)
for(i in seq_along(v1)) print(v1[i])
```